How do I award the same amount of bounty to another answer?
How do I adjust a correlation matrix whose elements are generated from different market regimes?
Have no idea why I can't award just +50 bounty to another answer(楊祝昇s) for which I am equally thankful? Now the minimum is +100 just for my question. I can set +50 for any other questions. Why?
Well, obviously I don't have much reputation to spare, so I hope there is a way to set the bounty lower. Any idea? Thanks! 

This is by design. See MSO, where they talked about this recent change to the system. It is to prevent bounty abuse. 

Thank you, Tal!
